# Choose or change the APK V1 signature scheme from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, signature

Visual Studio 2019 is able to sign the APK file of your Xamarin Android project, through the "Archive", "Distribute ...", "Ad Hoc" menu options.
I checked the signature of the .apk file I got, using the "apksigner.bat" file, which is part of the Android SDK ("C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.0") with the following command:

apksigner.bat verify --verbose --print-certs C:\App\temp\com.companyname.App1.apk

Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): false
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true

How to change the v1 scheme (JAR signing) as true using xamarin.android(VS2019)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add two packaging properties in the `.csproj` in order to use `ApkSigner` (instead of default `Jarsigner`) and enable v2 signing:

```
<AndroidUseApkSigner>True</AndroidUseApkSigner>
<AndroidApkSignerAdditionalArguments>--v2-signing-enabled true</AndroidApkSignerAdditionalArguments>
```

Comment: Where in the project file should these props go?